# Inject additional parameter in request using FastAPI

Tags: python, request, fastapi, starlette

I'm creating an API gateway using `fastAPI` for some microservices, which in I authenticate user via Azure AD via [fastapi-azure-auth](https://github.com/Intility/fastapi-azure-auth).
So I'm trying to take out the user info from the `request` object (`request.state.user`) and inject my own token in it to later pass to other microservices.

I tried using [app.middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/),

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    new_token = generate_token(request.state.user)
    request["new_token"] = new_token
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

but I'm getting following error at the initialization of the project:

> AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'user'

Also I tried creating a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def token_injector(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap_function(*args, **kwargs):
        user: User = kwargs['request'].state.user
        new_token = generate_token(user)
        kwargs["new_token"] = new_token # or kwargs['request']["new_token"] = new_token
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_function
```

and for this approach, I'm getting these errors:

> ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"),
> TypeError('vars() argument must have **dict** attribute')]

and

> TypeError: 'Request' object does not support item assignment

So does anyone have a solution for this?

**UPDATE**

Seems like it can't be done in middleware, cause the user info is added after it

Comment: Where does the `.user` property gets populated into the `request.state` object?

Comment: @MatsLindh It's done by `fastapi-azure-auth` library

Comment: But does that run before your middleware - since it's a dependency in the view and not a middleware? Do you handle if the user _isnt_ authenticated? They only set the `user` property if an actual valid JWT is available, so there might be paths through this where it doesn't get set? https://github.com/Intility/fastapi-azure-auth/blob/44c502969806231de3fb0dff28a3d9784f4234e8/fastapi_azure_auth/auth.py

Comment: @MatsLindh Yeah. It's running before my middleware. The library handles if user's not authenticated. I just need to take the user info after it's authenticated and add some extra data and create my own token to send to some APIs

Comment: @MatsLindh So are you suggesting me to overwrite some part of the library to inject my data in it?

Comment: How about creating a second dependency that wraps the first dependency? I.e. instead of depending on `azure_scheme`, you depend on your own wrapper, which in turn depends on `azure_scheme`; and your wrapper returns new_token, so that when you need it in a view function you add `new_token: str = Depends(get_new_token)` to the signature?

Comment: @MatsLindh I gotta admit, that's a lot for me to take in! I really need to think about how does that work. But thank you!

Comment: As it became a bit too verbose for a comment I've added an example as an answer - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MatsLindh. With a slightly change of his answer, I could find a working solution:

```
async def get_new_token(request: Request):
    # Generate new token
    request.state.new_token = 'NEW_TOKEN_HERE'

app.include_router(
    api_router,
    prefix=settings.API_V1_STR,
    dependencies=[Security(azure_scheme, scopes=['user_login'])],
)

@app.get('/foo')
async def actual_route(request: Request = Depends(get_new_token)):
    # Find new token in request.state.new_token
    pass
```

Comment: `get_new_token()` doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar enough with `fastapi-azure-auth` to know if this would work exactly as you'd need, but you could do something like:

```
async def get_new_token(request: Request, user_info=Security(azure_scheme, scopes='user_impersonation'):
    return 'my_freshly_generated_token:' + request.state.user

app.include_router(api_router, prefix=settings.API_V1_STR, dependencies=[Depends(get_new_token)])

@app.get('/foo')
async def actual_route(new_token: str = Depends(get_new_token)):
    # do magic
    pass
```

The actual dependency will only be evaluated once (so the router dependency will evaluate it, the view will get passed the returned value). Make sure to test that I haven't borked user authentication for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Although I get `TypeError: 'Depends' object is not iterable` error, which I can't understand how is this solution related to being iterable.

Comment: Did you leave out the `[]` around the value to `dependencies` in the router definition?

Comment: Thank you. Using this answer I could come up with a working one!